# IOS AppInvites.xcodeproj default project not working

Tags: ios, google-app-invites

I am having a problem with the latest version 1.0.2 of Google AppInvites for IOS. I was using the previous version 1.0.1 last month and it worked back then. But somehow the new version did not work anymore or Google had changed something recently on their backend.

I have installed Google's default AppInvitesExample.xcodeproj from: pod try Google
I have configured the bundle ID and reverse client id and got the correct GoogleService-Info.plist file.
Then I executed the xcworkspace and run the xcode project in iphone simulator.
Google Signin is working as I can see my name "Signed in as xxx".
But when I click the button "INVITE FRIENDS" the appinvite dialog appeared for a while but it automatically closes. After that, I will get the error:
"The operation couldn't be completed. (The caller does not have permission)"

Can anybody help ? Thanks !

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, and it seemed to magically go away when I tried it again a couple of hours later. Are you running into this issue consistently?